# Loop through references in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd appreciate if someone could advise me on my problem.

Each record in my table has a reference to another record, example:

```
ID      DEBIT_ACCT_NO   CREDIT_ACCT_NO  ID_REF  AS_OF_DATE

REF1    NOSTRO123       USD111          NULL    03.06.2015
REF2    USD111          USD222          REF1    08.06.2015
REF3    USD222          CLIENT1982      REF2    10.06.2015
```

Here, I need to find initial transaction for 3rd record (always where credit account is client account), the output will be

```
ID       INITIAL_ID
REF3     REF1
```

The number of such transitions can vary. It's given that the initial transaction will always have `DEBIT_ACCT_NO` equal `NOSTRO123`. I'm not sure if a CTE could help here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried? What is `INITIAL_ID`? Is it always the 1st reference based on `AS_OF_DATE`?

Comment: It certainly looks like a use-case for a recursive `cte`, what am I not seeing that makes you think a `cte` might not help?

Comment: CTE would definitely help, what you had tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps following [recursive SQL query](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-recursive-query-with-recursive-cte.aspx) can help you

```
;with cte as (
    select cast(a.ID as varchar(20)) as [Source], a.ID, a.ID_REF
    from accounts a where ID = 'REF3'
    union all
    select cte.Source, a.ID, a.ID_REF
    from accounts a
    inner join cte on cte.ID_REF = a.ID
)
select [Source] ID, ID ID_REF
from cte
where ID_REF is null
```